# VBA - Using if statements & need to locate exact matches in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have spent hours searching this site and others but can't find an applicable answer that works with my code - full disclosure being that I am a total beginner.

I have one sheet in excel that contains 1000s of lines of data. My macro (which works!) copies individual rows of data into separate sheets based on criteria in column F. Column F contains data such as CCCC 1, CCCC 2, ..., CCCC 10, CCCC 11 and the macro copies the rows into sheets C1, C2, ..., C10, C11.

My issue: Rows that contain CCCC 10 and CCCC 11 in column F are being copied into the C1 sheet but I only want rows containing CCCC 1 in the C1 sheet. I know the problem is that I am using the InStr function but I cannot figure the solution.

Important notes: Not every row has data in column F and I have column headers in my destination sheets.

Thank you in advance for any help

```
Sub SortVintage()
Dim r As Long, sv1 As Long, sv2 As Long
sv1 = Sheets("Input").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv2 = Sheets("C1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv3 = Sheets("C2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv4 = Sheets("C3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv5 = Sheets("C4").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv6 = Sheets("C5").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv7 = Sheets("C6").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv8 = Sheets("C7").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv9 = Sheets("C8").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv10 = Sheets("C9").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv11 = Sheets("C10").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sv12 = Sheets("C11").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For r = sv1 To 2 Step -1
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 1") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 1") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C1").Range("A" & sv2 + 1)
        sv2 = Sheets("C1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 2") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 2") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C2").Range("A" & sv3 + 1)
        sv3 = Sheets("C2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 3") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 3") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C3").Range("A" & sv4 + 1)
        sv4 = Sheets("C3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 4") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 4") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 4, Series 5") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C4").Range("A" & sv5 + 1)
        sv5 = Sheets("C4").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 5") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 5") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C5").Range("A" & sv6 + 1)
        sv6 = Sheets("C5").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 6") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 6") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C6").Range("A" & sv7 + 1)
        sv7 = Sheets("C6").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 7") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 7") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C7").Range("A" & sv8 + 1)
        sv8 = Sheets("C7").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 8") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 8") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C8").Range("A" & sv9 + 1)
        sv9 = Sheets("C8").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 9") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 9") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C9").Range("A" & sv10 + 1)
        sv10 = Sheets("C9").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 10") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 10") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C10").Range("A" & sv11 + 1)
        sv11 = Sheets("C10").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "CCCC 11") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, (Range("F" & r).Value), "Series 11") > 0 Then
        Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("C11").Range("A" & sv12 + 1)
        sv12 = Sheets("C11").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess the simplest fix would be to AND your IF: `If InStr(1, val, "CCCC 1") > 0 And InStr(1, val, "CCCC 11") > 0 then` must be CCCC 11 - not very efficient though, I think there's probably a neater way to write the entire thing...

Comment: Is the text "CCCC" repeated anywhere else in the string that's in a col F value? - you could just use the number after CCCC to define which sheet to copy to rather than testing for "CCCC x" just test for "CCCC" then pluck the number x and send to sheet x

Comment: @jamheadart it is the only value in the cell. What you suggested got me thinking but the issue would still be that CCCC 11 would show up in the C1 sheet whether because '1' is still in '11'

Comment: I think the best way to tackle it is one simple extraction of the number from the value in the F cell - below I've used the Right() function to pull the number (and included a test for the Series 4, Series 5 possibility) -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this routine instead:

```
Sub HeyHo()

Dim SV1 As Long
Dim cVal As String
Dim lROW As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim t As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input") 'Sets WS to your main input sheet
SV1 = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in input

On Error Resume Next

    For r = SV1 To 2 Step -1                ' Cycle through input from bottom to 2nd row
        t = 0
        cVal = WS.Cells(r, "F").Value2      ' set cVal to = "F" cell value
        t = Right(cVal, Len(cVal) - InStrRev(cVal, " ")) ' Extract rightmost value of "F" cell value
        If t = 5 Then If InStr(1, cVal, 4) Then t = 4 ' if t is 5 double check it isn't the Series 4, Series 5 possibility
        If t > 0 Then                       ' if no number was found then exit loop for this row else:
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C" & t) ' specify sheet where t is the extracted number
            lROW = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' get lastrow + 1 of the worksheet
            WS.Rows(r).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & lROW) ' copy row r from WS (Input) to specified t sheet lastrow + 1
        End With
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! I just need a little clarification so I can apply this - would I set a WS1 through WS12 for each destination sheet?

Comment: Nope, you wouldn't need to set the destination sheet, it is referred to in the `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C" & t)` part - everything that starts with a `.` inside the `With` knows it's referring to that sheet - hope that makes sense

Comment: I did set the main "Input" sheet as WS just to make referring to that one easier (it doesn't have a number) but for the C1 to C11 sheets I can just say "C" & t - where t is the number from 1 to 11

Comment: Okay that's cool and makes sense. I am getting a run-time error '13' type mismatch regarding the `t = Right(cVal, Len(cVal) - InStrRev(cVal, " "))`

Comment: Ah ok, it'll be because of empty cells or any cell where the last characters aren't numbers, I've updated the code with an Error catch in and also resetting t to 0 after each loop to prevent copying previously copied rows - please try that!

Comment: That worked for me and it ran at least 50% faster than my initial code. Thank you so much I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! You had most of it already there really, I just tried to get it all covered in one statement in a loop instead of doing the 11 different `if` conditions - clincher was using the number already in the column F to tell Excel which sheet to use